# google-apps-script Transient Internal error error 500

Tags: google-apps-script

I´ve been doing some scripts in gs, but lately I´m receiving the message "Transcient internal failure error 500" and I can´t give it  authorization to run. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged into multiple Google Accounts, you may get the 500 error during authorization.